# Grep getting numbers in a range

Tags: grep

I'm trying to display rows which include numbers in range 20-200 in column 12 from a csv file. However, I don't get the right input.

I tried this:

```
grep -E "^[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,([2-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|200)" file.csv > sc1_d.csv
```

What do I do wrong?
Any thoughts?

Comment: While `grep` is a tool for selecting parts from a text, it is only based on string operations and has no knowledge of numeric ranges or other advanced concepts. To this end it is better to use other tools such as `awk`. The answer of Ed Morton here nicely shows how you can achieve your task in a very readable way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues here.

(1) your way of finding column 12 won't work in any rows that have cells containing commas. And that's difficult to resolve unless you know who wrote the CSV file. Since there's no single CSV spec, there are multiple ways of escaping commas and quotes in CSV files. For example, in one spec, a comma within a cell is escaped with a backslash (for example, my doctor's name might be written as **`Dr. Bob\, MD`**. In another, any cell value that contains a comma needs to be put in double quotes, and double quotes themselves need to be written as two double quotes (so, **`"Dr. Bob, MD"`**).

But if for some reason you happen to know that embedded commas in cell values is not an issue in your CSV file, you can ignore that.

(2) That expression would also allow some other values, such as 201 or 20000B, that you don't want. So if you know that there this is not the last column, you can just add commas after the choices:

```
([2-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|200),
```

And if you can't make that assumption, then you can just look for a comma OR end of line:

```
([2-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|200)(,|$)
```

And finally you can employ a "repeat" to specify exactly 11 instances of the `[^,]*,` pattern. So now your grep command looks like this:

```
grep -E "^([^,]*,){11}([2-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|200)(,|$)" file.csv > sc1_d.csv
```

Answer (score 4):

Keep it simple, just use awk:

```
awk -F, '(20 <= $12) && ($12 <= 200)' file
```

If that doesn't do exactly what you want then edit your question to explain in what way this and your own attempt "don't get the right input" and to show concise, testable sample input and expected output.